# NOLOGGING is not functioning

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

This is a part of my code. Everything is ok, no error. But I have million of lines to be inserted. I searched the internet for ways to finish my job faster.

What I found, is that insert in table using nologgin and +append, but is not working. Time to insert the same lines in table is the same even I use nologging and append.

```
    create or replace procedure read_files(input varchar2, extensie varchar2) as  
........................................ 
    Loop
     BEGIN
..............................
        UTL_FILE.GET_line(F1,V1);
    insert /*+ append */ into alarms(alarm_id,property_name,property_value) 
    =values(alarm_counter,f_property_name,f_property_value) ;

     End loop;
    end; 


alter table alarms nologging;
execute read_files('occ','cap');
alter table alarms logging;
```

Steps for my work:

- first compile the procedure
- alter table nologging
- execute procedure

Where is my mistake?

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5280714813869

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APPEND hint only works with `INSERT .. SELECT` statements.  The [APPEND_VALUES](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#BABFIHGA) hint
 is meant for `INSERT .. VALUES` statements.

Direct-path inserts have several requirements and limitations.  Before trying the APPEND_VALUES hint it would be better to try FORALL.  It adds extra steps but it reduces the context switches between SQL and PL/SQL, which may significantly improve performance.

```
declare
    type alarm_counter_nt is table of number;
    type f_property_name_nt is table of varchar2(100);
    type f_property_value_nt is table of varchar2(100);
    alarm_counters alarm_counter_nt := alarm_counter_nt();
    property_names f_property_name_nt := f_property_name_nt();
    property_values f_property_value_nt := f_property_value_nt();
begin
    --Get values.
    loop
        utl_file_get_line(f1, v1);
        alarm_counters.extend;
        alarm_counters(alarm_counters.count) := ?;
        f_property_names.extend;
        f_proprety_names(f_property_names.count) := ?;
        f_property_values.extend;
        f_property_values(f_property_values.count) := ?;
    end loop;

    --Insert values.
    forall i in 1 .. alarm_counters.count
        insert into alarms(alarm_id,property_name,property_value) 
        values(alarm_counters(i),f_property_names(i),f_property_values(i)) ;

    commit;
end;
/
```